# Make end date value show exactly 1 year after user inputs start date and account for leap years

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Im still learning C# and I have a problem with my SAP add-on Payroll program.

I have a form where a user selects a starting period. I.e "01 January 2011" through a datetime picker (1) created through visual basic 2010.

I want another datetime picker (2) on the form to automatically show the ending period after exatcly one year. In the case of starting period = "01 January 2011", I want the ending period to be "31st December 2011".

My Code:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var endDate = default(DateTime);

     endDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(365);

     dateTimePicker2.Value = endDate;
}
```

My 2 problems.

1. The above does not account for leap years. How do I solve this?
2. With the above code, when 01 January 2011 is selected, the ending date is showing incorrectly, 01 January 2012, however when I input 01 march 2011, the ending date is showing correctly, 29 February 2012. Could this be related to the first problem?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems to take care of all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use **DateTime.AddYears** DateTime.AddYears(1);

Answer (score 0):

Is better to use

```
endDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddYears(1);
```

than  AddDays methods because some years have 366 days